# Taking every character literally in RegEx

Tags: c++, regex

Using `std::regex` I want to create a function that takes, for example, a string 
and creates a RegEx using that string, but with every char of the string matched literally.

For example, lets say `s("[ds-aa]")`; I want to create a RegEx using that string but literally so that the RegEx will match `"\[ds\-aa\]"`.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: maybe use hex representation. (`\xhh`)

Comment: Do you mean you want a regex as in '("[" + someString + "]")' so it matches based of a string variable?

Comment: Apart from it seems like you really need a straight *find* rather than *regex* what exactly is the question?

Comment: It seems the OP wants a quote function so that a regex can be built for example as `quote(a) + ".*" + quote(b)` to find exactly `a` then anything then exactly `b`

Comment: So basically, the question is: how to escape regex in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `std::regex`, and the default ECMA regex flavor, you just need to escape

```
. * + ? ^ $ { } ( ) | [ ] \
```

So, you can use

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string regexEscape(std::string str) {
    return std::regex_replace(str, std::regex(R"([.^$|()[\]{}*+?\\])"), R"(\$&)");
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test escaped pattern: " << regexEscape("[da-d$\\]")  << std::endl; // = > \[da-d\$\\\]
    std::string key = "\\56";
    string input = "John\\56 Fred\\12";
    std::regex rx(R"((\w+))" + regexEscape(key));
    smatch m;
    if (std::regex_search(input, m, rx)) {
        std::cout << "Who has \\56? - " << m[1].str() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/sfgOb1)

Results:

```
Test escaped pattern: \[da-d\$\\\]
Who has \56? - John
```